# How to generate Fedex test shipping label required for enabling production key?

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, fedex

I want to send them test shipping label for getting production key enabled from them. I don't know how to generate test shipping label in magento as I can't see any option to generate that. Please can anybody tell me how to get test shipping label and send them.

P.S : I am using Magento 1.9.2.4.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your issue is to generate and test the fedex api:

To generate test shipping label in your local environment follow [this](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/shipping/fedex.html)

After that go to admin > sales > orders and select an order. In the page that follows, click on ship and then Create Shipping Label. After successfully completing the next steps and you will see a print shipping label option. Click it to print the test shipping label.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option to generate a shipping label, Also make sure your FedEx account has registered your domain, otherwise shipping label will not generated,

[image]

Thanks & Regards,